# How to load page template and put content into?

Tags: php

Maybe it's duplicate but I don't know how it calls and cannot find. I need to load a php-file (template of my block) and set content into it.
For example, template file:

```
<?php include_once 'boot.inc' ?>
<div class="widget">
    <div class="widget-title">I need to put title here</div>
    <div class="widget-body">I need to put content here</div>
</div>
```

And php function to insert new block with this template:

```
function nm_new_block($title, $content) {};
```

Can I do it in php?

Comment: Have you tried putting `<?php echo $title; ?>` where it says "I need to put title here", and `include 'template_file.php';` as the body of your function?

Comment: Yeah, where it says "I need to put title/content here" it needs to replace by `$title` and `$content` values from function arguments

Comment: Sorry, I'm noobie in php. Can you post code example?

Comment: Well, try my suggestion (code example in my previous comment) and see what happens. Btw, you might want to look into [template engines](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+php+template).

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thank you, brother!

Comment: :-) Nice! You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

1° Solution: You need to change you code into:

```
<?php include_once 'boot.inc' ?>
<?php include_once 'template.php'  ?>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-title"><?php echo $title; ?></div>
        <div class="widget-body"><?php echo $content; ?></div>
    </div>
```

In `template.php` file you must have something like this:

```
<?php
    $title="My Title";
    $content="My Content";
?>
```

And you don't need function for this cause variables are stored in `template.php`

---

2° Solution: You need to implement a function to retrieve variables from external source:

```
<?php include_once 'boot.inc' ?>
<?php include 'functions.php' ?>
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-title"><?php echoTitle(); ?></div>
        <div class="widget-body"><?php echoContent(); ?></div>
    </div>
```

In `functions.php`

```
<?php
function echoTitle(){
    $title = 'Add code to get title here';
    echo $title;
}
function echoContent(){
    $content = 'Add code to get content here';
    echo $content;
}
```

Replace `Add code to get title here` and `Add code to get content here` with code to get contents ex:

`$title = $_POST['title'];` supposing you want get title by a submission form

I do not have enough details to tell you more.

Comment: Thanks! I know these ways but in my case it's not very good solution, unfortunately.